# delphi eventos OnkeyDown e OnExit

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Tenho o seguinte código nos eventos:

OnExit:

```
procedure TFEqt_Pallet.EdNr_PalletExit(Sender: TObject);
var
 MeuKey: word;
begin
 MeuKey := 13;
 EdNr_PalletKeyDown(EdNr_Pallet,MeuKey,[]); 
end;
```

OnKeyDown:

```
procedure TFEqt_Pallet.EdNr_PalletKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
Shift: TShiftState);
begin
if Ord(key) = 13 then
begin
...
 proximocampo.setfocus;
end;
```

Quando dou um enter no componente ele esta chamando o método OnExit duas vezes. Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Não esta certo chamar um evento de dentro de outro evento. Reformule a sua lógica para que isso não ocorra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você pressiona a tecla Enter no Edit, seu procedure KeyDown realizar uma serie de coisas e no final "seta" o foco em outro componente, quando isso ocorre, o procedure OnExit é chamado e, por sua vez, ele chama novamente o procedure KeyDown, por isso essa repetição.

Acredito que você esteja fazendo isso porque quer executar uma série de procedimentos quando o usuário apertar enter e/ou sair do Edit.

Você deve colocar esses procedimentos no onExit e no onKeyDown apenas o setfocus para o proximo componente.

Exemplo:

OnExit:

```
procedure TFEqt_Pallet.EdNr_PalletExit(Sender: TObject);
var
 MeuKey: word;
begin
 O aque eu quero que faça.
end;
```

OnKeyDown:

```
procedure TFEqt_Pallet.EdNr_PalletKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
Shift: TShiftState);
begin
if Ord(key) = 13 then
begin
 proximocampo.setfocus;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

O ideal é não ter controle de troca de foco dentro de componentes, deixe isso para o formulário. Siga os passos abaixo e melhore um pouco seu fonte

1. Configure corretamente os TabOrder's dos componentes do seu
   formulário.
2. Ative o KeyPreview do form.
3. No evento KeyDown do form coloque o código:

`if Key = VK_RETURN then
  Perform(WM_NEXTDLGCTL, 0, 0);`

Dica: Não utilize controle de foco no OnExit de componentes. Se você está em um componente e resolve voltar em outro clicando com o mouse, o foco não vai p onde deveria. Isso irrita.

Comment: Adicionei o seu código no KeyDown, mas continua com o mesmo problema, quando uso o Enter ele chama duas vezes o OnkeyDown e uma o OnExit.